# How do I checkout a tag/release in Teamcity when working agains Git?

Tags: tags, clone, teamcity

When working with Teamcity I wanted to specify the tag from which do the clone in order to deploy the correct version to production in the next build step.

I usually specify "master" on the "development" stage so I deploy the current snapshot version to this environment, so I was trying to specify "/tags/projectName-1.0" for production deployment.

I always get an error on the VCS origin as not being able to clone the tag.

How do I specify to clone from an existing tag?

Answer (score 3):

To specify that you want to clone from a tag (for whatever reason) you have to specify it in the following format:

refs/tags/projectname-1.0

Answer (score 0):

In your vcs root there's a box called Branch Name:  its contains some thing like refs/tags/build-v0.2.2.55  where build-v0.2.2.55 is your existing tag.

Comment: Thanks James, but this is why I answered my own question. There's no reference to "refs/tags", so it's not straight forward to know that you have to use this. It only tells you to specify the branch/tag name, and if you do so, it does not work: i.e. "1.0-M02" would not work but "refs/tags/1.0-M02" would.

Comment: yeah didnt see your answer.